# Prefered format when swizzling in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I want to load a texture which is layed out in memory as ARGB (with 1 byte components). Therefore when loading it with Vulkan, **I need to apply a texture swizzle** to it, as there is no ARGB pixel format in Vulkan.

My question is, should I prefer using `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` over `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` or the other way around?

PD: This texture will be used only once and then updated

Edit: Please note that the available alternatives are:

- `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`
- `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`
- `VK_FORMAT_A8B8G8R8_UNORM_PACK32` (equivalent to `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` on LE systems, therefore I will ignore it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the two non-packed types are required image formats in Vulkan and therefore will always be present in Vulkan implementations for most kinds of image usage. So long as you're not using the format for buffer views, image load/store, or as an attachment, there is no Vulkan-detectable reason to prefer one format over the other.

Since you are going to apply a swizzle mask to the image view, the order of components in the format isn't all that relevant to texture sampling operations.

As such, which one you use is just a matter of taste.